# (gcloud.projects.list) PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, credentials, gcloud

I have a machine that needs to run the following gcloud command: 
`gcloud projects list --format=json`

The output error that gives me: 
`ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.`

Is pretty obvious that the current configuration and account set for the machine do not have the permissions.

Funny that when I use `gcloud compute instances list --project=<project_ID> --format=json`

It gives me a list of the machines listed in the project I specify.

I enabled the [Google Resource Manager API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com?pli=1)

I even created some service account credentials and activated them in the machine. Still the same error.

In the [SDK documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list) there is no reference on how to enable credentials to see other projects

Anyone had this issue before? I saw outdated questions whose solutions didn't work out for me.

**Edit**

I should mention that the machine in question is a GCE instance and there is no way (unless I install manually the SDK, which is a mess I am not going to get into) to update the SDK.

Cloud API access scopes are set manually and there is no mention of the "Resource Manager" and i can't seem to add or remove any new API Accesses

Comment: I would double check what account is active with `gcloud config list`. If you are running it on GCE, by default you are going to get a GCE service account as active and that account probably doesn't have access to this API.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mark I checked it and the account should at least see two of them because is an account shared between two projects.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list), `gcloud projects list` shows all the active projects were the account has the Owner, Editor or Viewer project level role. As long as the service account you activated in your instance has one of those roles in a gcp project, you should be able to run the command.

For example, from your cloud shell grant the viewer role to your service account:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <your_project_id> \
--member serviceAccount:<your_service_account> --role roles/viewer
```

Activate the service account in your instance using the [json key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys):

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/key.json
```

Run the projects list command:

```
gcloud projects list --format=json
```

Comment: You're right! I set the instance to "Allow Full Access to all APIs" and it works.
Problem is I don't want to allow full access, so now I am pinpointing the exact access scope to set only this one alone. I will update once I find it.

Comment: I gave up. I couldn't find the specific access scope even though I know it's the resource manager. The only way to add/remove scopes is through gcloud but I searched and I didn't find the available scopes. 
I'm leaving the VM instance configurated to "Allow Full Access to all APIs"

Comment: @Wiggin, The procedure I described above should work regardless of the scopes defined at instance level, as long as you activate a service account that is either viewer, editor or owner first. If you are using the service account you assigned to your instance at instance creation, then your approach is fine.